# Blink notification/confirmation with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click a certain element, I would like to see a **confirm** appear and fade out. I have achieved this with the below code, but I am not 100% happy, because it cannot be used quickly twice in a row. I need to wait for the text to disappear (and reappear while hidden) before clicking again. There must be a better way to do this kind of magic.

Here is what I did:

```js
$(".hello").click(function() {
  var element = $(".conf");
  blink(element);
  setTimeout(function() {
    reset(element);
  }, 2000);
});

function blink(element, callback) {
  element.css('visibility', 'visible');
  element.css('opacity', '0');
}

function reset(element) {
  element.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  element.css('opacity', '1');
}
```

```css
.hello {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.conf {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lime;
  color: black;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="hello">hello</span>
<span class="conf">confirmation</span>
```

Comment: @Chris G: thanks for the edit. Didn't realize I can do it this way - awesome! :)

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vnqLoe9x/

Comment: Chris G: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the issue you can hide the element using `display: none`, then `show()` it on click and immediately fade it out. If you also call `stop()` on each event you will stop the `fadeOut()` animation and set the element back to a fully visible state. Try this:

```js
$(".hello").click(function() {
  $(".conf").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(1000);    
});
```

```css
.hello {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.conf {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lime;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="hello">hello</span>
<span class="conf">confirmation</span>
```